# .com/ VS .com in external links

Tags: html, xhtml

When we give link of external sites then how we should give link?

This

```
http://www.sitename.com/
```

or this

```
http://www.sitename.com
```

Are both same?

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The second will be converted to the first, because it will be sent as:

```
   GET / HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.sitename.com
```

The path component is an abs_path, and [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) says these must begin with a /.

Comment: So is it better to give First?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, since any user agent will do the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Remember though that while this may be a matter of taste, there are situations where keeping the trailing slash is **better** practice. See an extensive discussion here:

http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/thou-must-not-steal-the-trailing-slash-from-my-urls/